# yyyy-MM-dd date format in Export to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, date-format, openxml-sdk

Is there any way for getting date alone from UniversalSortableDateTimePattern using this in Export to Excel function. The Excel doesn't accepts the date format..
 I need to display as yyyy-MM-dd. 
Any suggestions ll be helpful ?
My code as

```
 dtASalesDrivers.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Start Date", typeof(String)));
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtATrendStartDate.Text);
 drASalesDrivers[2] = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dt);
dtASalesDrivers.Rows.Add(drASalesDrivers);
```

Edit :

```
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtATrendStartDate.Text);
            drASalesDrivers[2] = string.Format("{0:u}", dt);
```

This displays both date and time. Is there any way for displaying only date ???

Comment: Maybe use `DateTime.Parse` instead of `ToDateTime`, then `DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`? Also what exactly is the content of `txtATrendStartDate.Text`?

Comment: I tried DateTime.Parse but no changes in excel. txtAtrendStartDate.Text is a text box with date value eg: 2010-09-10. But this gets changed as 09/10/2010 in excel.

Comment: FYI, I've had great success with dates and EPPlus!

Answer (score 5):

I think that is to do with your computers settings.

If you open up a new instance of Excel and type `2012-07-24` and navigate away from the cell, it will instantly change to `24/07/2012`, it is more your computers regional settings than anything to do with your code.

You can however format the cell to `yyyy-mm-dd;@` so you may need to do this programmatically and not change anything else, I think that this may work:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtATrendStartDate.Text);
drASalesDrivers[2] = string.Format("{0:u}", dt);
drASalesDrivers[2].NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@";
```

But I haven't tested it

I was doing some messing around and some example code is below:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application _excelApp = new Application();
            Workbook workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx");

            Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
            Range excelRange = sheet.get_Range("A1");

            //If you comment the next line of code, you get '24/07/2012', if not you get '2012-07-24'
            excelRange.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@";

            excelRange.Value2 = "2012-07-13";

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close(false, @"C:\test\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx", null);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, `string.Format("{0:u}", dt);` will indeed return a date and a time, `dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` will return your date.

The alrernative is to change your `Short date` setting on your computer to yyy-MM-dd like so:

[image: Date Settings]

This will make your date appear how you want by default on Excel on your computer, but it will look differently on different computers.

Comment: how does numberformat applied to this ?. Do i have to use CultureInfo reference ?

Comment: What happens if you change `drASalesDrivers[2] = string.Format("{0:u}", dt);` to `drASalesDrivers[2] = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`?

Answer (score 1):

here is my code, I realize it by following code:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange;
excelRange = worksheet.get_Range("H2", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
excelRange.NumberFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd;@";
```