# C# : Error Printing the Date Value in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I am building a `winform` based Desktop application. As part of the application, I am generating the Excel output.

I am getting  a error, when I am trying to enter the date value.

In C#, the date value is `"11-10-12"`. However, in Excel, it is printing as `10-11-2012`.

Here is the code, which does it :

```
String Date1 = "11-10-12";
oSheet.Cells[i + 2, 1] = DateTime.ParseExact(Date1, "dd-MM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Any idea what could could be wrong ?

**EDIT**

The Cell format in Excel was by default General. However, when the values are entered, it is changed to Date.

[image]

Comment: Kiran what does the exact error say..?

Comment: Could be because of your excel date format options?

Comment: I think the only one at fault here is Excel. It's choosing a different date format against your will. But, may I ask why on Earth you're using a two-digit year in your input and not a four-digit one?

Comment: I don't think Excel is at fault, it is supposed to show dates as your computer's regional settings dictate unless you specify otherwise by altering the Format property of the cell, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11629655/969613) may help

Comment: @DJKRAZE, There is no error message. Its a logical error. I would like to print 11th Oct 2012, However, it is printing 11th Nov 2012.

Comment: Check your Format Cells-->Number-->Date format in your excel. Or could be a regional settings issue.

Comment: Your code works it sounds like you have a cell format set incorrectly..

Comment: @SonerGönül, I will check it. If the Date is unambiguous for instance, 31-10-12, it prints properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the suggestion helped unfortunately. So, I disabled the automatic formatting in Excel :

So, here is the code snippet which disables the automatic (Date) formatting in Excel :

```
String Date1 = "11-10-12";
oSheet.Cells[i + 2, 1] = "'" + Date1;
```

So, the trick is to preceed the String with an apostrophe which worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the format of the excel-Cell with:

```
yourCellRange.NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yy";
```

or adjust the string format to the excel-format.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. However, it did not help. I am editing my question to give some additional information

Answer (score 1):

Try just:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
```

or:

```
String Date1 = "11-10-12";
var Format = "dd-MM-yy";
var TimeBuff = DateTime.ParseExact(Date1, Format, 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(Format);
oSheet.Cells[i + 2, 1] = TimeBuff;
```

Both Parse and ToString must contains the same Format. If you get the same its definitely a Excel failure.

Edit:

[image: Evidence]

Just for DJ KRAZE

[image: Evidence]

Comment: your answer is incorrect.. if you run his code in a debugger it will yield a value of `10-11-2012` before posting and answer perhaps you may want to test the code on your side first..

Comment: Both Returns 18-01-13 in my Debugger Pic is Uploading

Comment: read the OP's Question he wants a 4 digit year not a 2 digit year so your answer is therefore incorrect
runt this code and you will see what I mean `String Date1 = "11-10-12";
var tempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Date1, "dd-MM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`

Comment: Zitat:
"I am getting a error, when I am trying to enter the date value.

In C#, the date value is "11-10-12". However, in Excel, it is printing as 10-11-2012."

If i Read this, it sounds like the opposite what you say

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
worksheet.get_Range(Cell1, Cell2 + worksheet.Rows.Count).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy";
```

When you are adding the value you can try

```
worksheet.Cells[row, column] = String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", Date1);
```

Comment: NO,it was not successful. I just cannot enter a string "03-02-2013" which is 3rd Feb 2013. However, Excel interprets as 2nd Mar 2013. I have the cell format set to "General"