# "12/2013" in cell automatically changes to "12/1/2013"

Tags: excel, vba

in excel, how to prevent this automatic changing of values like: "12/2013" to "12/1/2013"

if i enter "12/2013" in a cell it is auto changed to "12/1/2013". i donot want this.

Because I want to search for exact "12/2013" later using vba.

Comment: possible duplicate of [yyyy-MM-dd date format in Export to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629472/yyyy-mm-dd-date-format-in-export-to-excel)

Comment: Change the cell data format to Text?

Comment: thanks thomas. please post as answer i will mark as accepted

Comment: Alternatively to keep its "dateness" format it as custom and enter `mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the cell(or cells after selecting them) ->  Format Cells -> Number -> Text and re-enter the data of course.

Comment: why negative rep? this is same thing i used which is suggested by @Thomas Owers first!

Comment: @VppMan, no idea what is going on? If the answer is not correct, down-voter should tell the public why it is not good so that also I learn what is good.

Comment: well, still it is a correct answer , i dont understand some people ( ill upvote;) )

Comment: i haven't used excel alot but does it not have a format option similar to access where you could specify a date format like mm/yyyy?

Comment: @Katana24 yes it does have, but excel sucks this time. Whenever I enter something similar to a date somehow, it changes without asking it. Try to enter 7/22 in a cell, and see what happens.

Comment: it changed to 22 july - but then i changed the format to Custom | Typed in mm/yyyy and it sticks - i typed in your 12/2013 and it doesn't change

Comment: @Katana24 at just moment, you decided to enter 12/13. Again, you have to change it. Believe me, this might be the only thing that excel is not excellent.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `'` as a prefix, i.e. enter `'12/2013`- or format the column/cell as text beforehand.

Comment: Correct, if by suffix you mean prefix :)